# ActionMailer::Base.deliveries is giving blank array when i am using sidekiq ? any configuration do we need to do for that

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq, ruby-on-rails-5.2, rspec-sidekiq

ActionMailer::Base.deliveries are giving blank array  when i am using sidekiq ?
any configuration do we need to do for that

My test.rb looks like this 
In development mode it is working fine and even from  test  sidekiq  shows no error.

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # The test environment is used exclusively to run your application's
  # test suite. You never need to work with it otherwise. Remember that
  # your test database is "scratch space" for the test suite and is wiped
  # and recreated between test runs. Don't rely on the data there!
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Do not eager load code on boot. This avoids loading your whole application
  # just for the purpose of running a single test. If you are using a tool that
  # preloads Rails for running tests, you may have to set it to true.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Configure public file server for tests with Cache-Control for performance.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = true
  config.public_file_server.headers = {
    'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{12.hour.to_i}"
  }

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Raise exceptions instead of rendering exception templates.
  config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false

  # Disable request forgery protection in test environment.
  config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false

  # Store uploaded files on the local file system in a temporary directory
  config.active_storage.service = :test

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq

  # Tell Action Mailer not to deliver emails to the real world.
  # The :test delivery method accumulates sent emails in the
  # ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array.
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test

  # Print deprecation notices to the stderr.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true

  # Access to rack session
  config.middleware.use RackSessionAccess::Middleware
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "localhost:3000" }
end
```

Comment: How did you trigger email sending? Did you call `SomeMailer.your_email_method.deliver_later`?

Comment: yes i wrote the same in worker with deliver_now

Comment: Where are you checking if its empty. I am assuming its in a spec somewhere. Post the code to that please